# How to draw a rectangle with one side as a half circle in flutter?

Tags: flutter, clip

This is what I am trying to achieve (excuse the imperfection but you get the idea):

[image: The shape I am trying to draw]

I see some tutorials using clipper but they dont seem to achieve what I want, I need to use a container to draw this as I want to place some text over it.

```
class DrawCustomCircle extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final Path path = new Path();
    ...
    return path;
  }
  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `BoxDecoration` to make this shape:

```
Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue,
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
              left: Radius.circular(50.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Result:

[image: res]